# How does CUDA handle multiple updates to memory address?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia

I have written a CUDA kernel in which each thread makes an update to a particular memory address (with int size). Some threads might want to update this address simultaneously.

How does CUDA handle this? Does the operation become atomic? Does this increase the latency of my application in any way? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation does not become atomic, and it is essentially undefined behavior.  When two or more threads write to the same location, one of the values will end up in the location, but there is no way to predict which one.

It can be especially problematic if you are reading and writing, such as to increment a variable.

CUDA provides a set of [atomic operations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) to help.

You may also use other coding techniques such as parallel reductions, to help when there are multiple updates to the same location, such as finding a max or min value.

If you don't care about the order of updates, it should not be a performance issue for newer GPUs which automatically condense writes or reads to a single location in global memory or shared memory, but this is also not specified behavior.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I needed!